# F4 function key in minix 3.1.3

Tags: operating-system, minix

how to test <kbd>F4</kbd> function key for process table printing in minix 3.1.3 installed in virtual box?

After rebooting and login , when i press <kbd>F4</kbd> key , project window in my PC opens . I haven't modified kernel till now.

Can someone tell me how to test functionality of <kbd>F4</kbd> key in minix 3.1.3?

Answer (score 1):

In Minix, the kernel and Information Server are in two different "spaces".  Minix is currently "mapping" things, for example a process table, into the IS space.

Anyway, the F4 keys are defined in /usr/src/services/is/dmp.c, the functions related to the <kbd>F4</kbd> keys are in .../kernel_dmp.c, and the function prototypes are in .../proto.h.

Don't forget to 'make install' in the directory you changed, then reboot.  And for God's sake, clone just in case.

Hope this helps.